# Which HTML5 Canvas library is faster KineticJS or EaselJS?

Tags: html, mobile, canvas, kineticjs, easeljs

I tried to compare [KineticJS](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/) and [EaselJS](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS).

**Which of the two libraries is faster on mobile devices?**

Comment: Generally, canvas on mobile is a bottleneck--less with recent os versions, even less with faster devices, much less on dual-processor devices, almost non-issue with GPU equipped mobile. However, performance is very much [App | O/S | device] dependent...you'll have to do app & device specific tests!  You'll need to test anyway because different configurations have insidious variations of canvas glitches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As markE said, you have to test performance by yourself. It is really depend on what type of application you have. `KineticJS` may be slower because it has really high level architecture, and my opinion that event model of KineticJS is the best.

If you need as fast, as possible. Don't use any library. Just "pure" canvas.

You can look at my performace test here: http://slash-system.com/en/comparing-drawning-approaches-for-web/. In this case `EaselJS` has the best performance results. (I was not doing any hard optimization for each library, just simplest way, also the `FastLayer` class was introduced in new `KineticJS` version, I was not using this type of layer.)

Comment: Agreed. Performance is going to be dependent on your usage. If you have a lot of vectors, it can actually come down to the browser. Both EaselJS and KineticJS are multi-use libraries, so a pure canvas approach may be faster because you can optimize for your specific use-case. If you are using Bitmaps, you might try EaselJS's SpriteContainer, which optimizes calls for the GPU, and is crazy fast. http://blog.createjs.com/webgl-easeljs-a-technical-intro/